# Passing parameters to Node() and LaunchDescription()

Tags: ros2

I am lost :)
Here is the problem (ROS2). Say, I have

```
params_file = LaunchConfiguration('params_file')
declare_params_file_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'params_file',
    default_value=def_nav2_params_path 
        if robots[0]['name']=='' else def_nav2_params_path_multi,
    description='Full path to the ROS2 parameters file to use for all launched nodes')
```

Now I have access to this command line parameter in some node:

```
params_file = LaunchConfiguration('params_file')
```

So far so good.

But let's say I want to modify the file in a "calling" code:

```
namespaced_params = ReplaceString(
    source_file=params_file, replacements={
        "namespace"  :  (namespace),                # /robot1
        "robot_name" :  (robot['name']),            # robot1                
    }
)
```

Now I want the node to use that modified file:

```
robot_localization_node = Node(
    package='robot_localization',
    executable='ekf_node',
    name='ekf_filter_node',
    namespace=namespace,
    output='screen',
    parameters=[namespaced_params, {'use_sim_time': use_sim_time }]
)
```

It works fine.
However, we also have LaunchDescriptions, so I can call one launch file from another:

```
IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(def_launch_dir, 'bringup_launch.py')),
    condition=LaunchConfigurationNotEquals('mode', 'simple'),
    launch_arguments={
        'namespace': namespace,
        'use_namespace': 'True',
        'slam': slam,
        'map': map_yaml_file,
        'keepout_mask': keepout_mask,
        'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
        'params_file': namespaced_params,
        'default_bt_xml_filename': default_bt_xml_filename,
        'autostart': 'True' }.items()),
])
```

Here, I have passed **namespaced_params** to launch file, but I have no idea how to use it!
Because in that launch file I see the already familiar

```
params_file = LaunchConfiguration('params_file')
```

which reads a command line argument, so I assume, it will get an initial, non-modifier params file. So how can I access **namespaced_params**?

Thank you.

=================

I'll try to rephrase it shorter: if in a "main" launch file I have

```
params_file = LaunchConfiguration('params_file')
declare_params_file_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'params_file',
    default_value=def_nav2_params_path 
        if robots[0]['name']=='' else def_nav2_params_path_multi,
    description='Full path to the ROS2 parameters file to use for all launched nodes')
```

and then I do this:

```
namespaced_params = ReplaceString(
    source_file=params_file, replacements={
        "namespace"  :  (namespace),                # /robot1
        "robot_name" :  (robot['name']),            # robot1                
    }
)
```

and pass namespaced_params as one of launch_arguments:

```
IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(os.path.join(def_launch_dir, 'bringup_launch.py')),
    condition=LaunchConfigurationNotEquals('mode', 'simple'),
    launch_arguments={
        'namespace': namespace,
        'use_namespace': 'True',
        'slam': slam,
        'map': map_yaml_file,
        'keepout_mask': keepout_mask,
        'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
        'params_file': namespaced_params,
        'default_bt_xml_filename': default_bt_xml_filename,
        'autostart': 'True' }.items()),
])
```

Then which of the two will I get inside bringup_launch.py, when I issue
params_file = LaunchConfiguration('params_file')
?

In other words, how can I access launch_arguments that I passed to bringup_launch.py?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it all out.
A fully functional example at https://robotics.snowcron.com, in the "multiple robots" section.

Comment: This seems to be a link only answer. If the link dies then your answer will not be much use. Please [edit] and add the relevant details from the link.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Steve Brown. I followed your link but there is no obvious answer there. Please *edit your answer* to explain what steps you needed to follow to resolve your question.

Comment: I am away from the comp. now, but I will in 2 weeks, hope it is ok.

Comment: Hello @SteveBrown, any updates?

Comment: A fully functioning implementation is available by the link. Briefly, I cheated. I ignored params_file, and passed namespaced_params as an additional parameter. Now, in a target file, I can use namespaced_params parameter, and it doesn't interfere with params_file.